# Liferay - Maven -Missing artifact com.liferay.portal in default portlet

Tags: eclipse, maven, liferay, maven-3, liferay-6

I'm creating a liferay portlet using IDE. When I create a new portlet using eclipse and select maven, the project which is generated by default gives following error.

PS: I haven't done any modification in  it.

> ```
> Failed to execute goal on project HelloWorldLR: Could not resolve 
> dependencies for project com.st.nidhi:HelloWorldLR:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
> The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
>    com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar:6.2, 
>    com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar:6.2, 
>    com.liferay.portal:util-taglib:jar:6.2, 
>    com.liferay.portal:util-java:jar:6.2: Failure to find
>    com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar:6.2 in 
>    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
>     resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
>     has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
> ```

---

Here is pom.xml fragment where I get error:

> Missing artifact com.liferay.portal
>
> ```
>  <dependency>
>               <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
>               <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
>               <version>${liferay.version}</version>
>               <scope>provided</scope>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
>               <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
>               <version>${liferay.version}</version>
>               <scope>provided</scope>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
>               <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
>               <version>${liferay.version}</version>
>               <scope>provided</scope>
>           </dependency>
> ```

I'm using

- Liferay version: 6.2
- Maven: 3
- Eclipse Luna

Any idea why??

Answer (score 1):

I had created the properties tag on the pom like this and everything run OK

```
<properties>
     <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score -1):

We just get the jars from Liferay and install them using "mvn install" command. After that make sure you are not using "embeded" maven. Instead use the maven from your maven folder. Hope this helps.